# dynamic loading of cron time for a spring batch job

Tags: cron, spring-batch

Requirement is :a spring batch job to be run on a particular time for different countries.

currently,"cron" time is loaded from a property file.can i dynamically change the cron time for a particular country from sql database.

conclusion: cron time needs to be loaded based on country.

current configuration:

```html
<bean id="taskscheduler" class="main.java.com.asbatch.newsfeed.BatchTaskScheduler"/> 


 <task:scheduled-tasks>
 <task:scheduled ref="taskscheduler" method="run" cron="${newsfeed_time}"/>
  </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

BatchTaskScheduler class

```
public class BatchTaskScheduler
```

{

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncher launcher;

@Autowired
private Job job;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BatchTaskScheduler.class);

public void run()
{

    try
    {
       launcher.run(job, new JobParameters());

    }
    catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e)
    {
        LOGGER.info("JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: " + e);

    }
    catch (JobRestartException e)
    {

       LOGGER.info("JobRestartException: " + e);

    }
    catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e)
    {

        LOGGER.info("JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: " + e);

    }
    catch (JobParametersInvalidException e)
    {

        LOGGER.info("JobParametersInvalidException: " + e);

    }
}
```

}

can any body please help me on this ?

Comment: Are you having 1 job for all countries or each country has individual job? Anyway, I'm thinking a simple way, let @Schedule handle a simple task mean let say every 1 min it will kick off the job. And in the job, we put a condition for each country to see if we really want to kick off the *real* functionality

Comment: currently all countries use a single time,which loaded from property file.i need to specify different time for different countries..say like 10 am at uk,12 am at france..etc..

Comment: I'm trying to say is you handle that logic in job itself, not from cron such as

    public void run() {
      if (shouldBeExecutedByCountry(country) {
         // shouldBeExecutedByCountry method, you will query table to return true/false
      }
    }

Comment: understood ..can you guide me through a sample example..? can i override run() ..?